# How to add triples to a jena Query

Tags: java, sparql, jena

Suppose I have some jena query object :

```
String query = "SELECT * WHERE{ ?s <some_uri> ?o ...etc. }";
Query q = QueryFactory.create(query, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
```

How would one go about getting information about the jena query object and adding in triples to it iteratively in an effective manner?  For example, suppose I wanted to add in the triples

```
?o dcterms:title "TheBestTitle".
?o dcterms:date ?date.
```

to the query, and perhaps more.
Is there some way to add in these triples to the query, or do some magic to create a new query object which looks like the original with those triples added in? Assume that I may need to grab information from the original version of the query as well (for example, List resultVars = q.getResultVars();).

Some leads I have are to use the AlgebraGenerator and Op Classes provided by the Jena API, but I can't seem to find any reasonable use cases in a context such as this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/manipulating_sparql_using_arq.html

1. Construct an algebra expression and convert to a query (OpAsQuery)
2. The Query object, which is the cleaned up parsed struture, can be manipulated (`Query.getQueryPattern`)
3. Do it by string manipulation before parsing.